# using ID in dataloader mapping file

Tags: data-loader

I'm using the *commandline dataloader* to do an `upsert`.
The datafile looks like this:

```
ID,COLUMN2,COLUMN3
965832145,2013,04
```

The `sfdc.externalIdField` property is set to "Id". 
Mapping-file: `ID=Account__r\:CustomerNr__c`

datafile encoding: UTF-8
dataloader-version: 22.0

**problem**

The succesfile contains `"ID","?ID","COLUMN2","COLUMN3"`
The errorfile contains `"?ID","COLUMN2","COLUMN3"`
None of the records were `inserted/updated`

Salesforce is rendering an extra ?

Comment: Is there an error in the error file ?

Comment: yes, there were errors in the error file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the name of the ID column in your source CSV file to be anything other than "ID". When the Success file is returned it will have an ID column created by Salesforce with the 18 character Id.

I'm guessing that the ? has been appended to avoid the column naming conflict. Note that a quick test with the Data loader GUI couldn't verify this. (I see that you are using the command line in your question, the GUI suited me for a quick test case.)

Failing that I'd suspect a hidden character encoded before the ID column header. Such characters will often be replaced with a `?` when they can't be interpreted correctly. Try converting your input CSV to ANSI and check how the ID column header appears.

Comment: Converting the file to ANSI solved the problem.

Using \uFEFFID=Account__r\:CustomerNr__c in the mapping file worked as well if the file was UTF-8. But I don't think that's the way to go :)

In the succes file the contents of the ID column was replaced by the salesforce ID.

Comment: Ah, glad that fixed it. [\uFEFF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) is a "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE", so it would be hard to pick in the UTF-8 file.

Answer (score 0):

try working with salesforce dataloader version 26 or before.. u will get no errors and the records will be updated with the special charcters.

Comment: Are you sure of this, mind referencing some documentation on this ?